# How do I access the To Do list "Steps" in the Outlook object model?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have written an Excel macro that opens Outlook, accesses the To Do List by returning the Items List from the olfoldertodo.  I can get the Item.Subject, Item.DueDate, etc.  However, I am unable to determine where in the object model "Steps" are stored.

See the image below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZWuM.png)

I have looked all through the Outlook object model.  I have also stepped through the code and looking through the Immediate and Locals windows to try to determine where Steps are stored, but thus far I have been unable to find the data in the object model.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.